# NewSoftSerial library is not working for me

Tags: arduino

I am trying to get the data from GY-NEO6MV2 GPS and I've tried every solution, but I stil get error:
C:\Users\Szymon\Documents\Arduino\libraries\NewSoftSerial\NewSoftSerial.cpp:43:10: fatal error: WConstants.h: No such file or directory

I use the most simple possible code, it only includes the library and does nothing else, so it's not a problem with my code.
None of the solutions from the internet is working, anybody has an idea why it is not working?

Comment: the SoftwareSerial library bundled with the AVR boards package in Arduino IDE is the same library. so delete NewSoftSerial and use SoftwareSerial

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've already tried to use SoftwareSerial library, but the problem is that I can't find an official version of the library. The only one I've found is this one https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/SoftwareSerial but it generates a lot of error

Comment: it is already installed, because it is platform depended it is bundled with the boards package. what arduino do you have?

Comment: I have arduino m0. I deleted the SoftwareSerial library from the libraries folder, but now I get "SoftwareSerial.h: No such file or directory"

Comment: there is no SoftwareSerial for SAMD architecture, because there is Serial1 on Rx/TX pins and you can create even more hardware Serials on any pins if needed.

Comment: And if I wanted to use Serial1 to read from rx and tx, then how to do this? I tried Serial1.read(), but it's not working

Comment: did you wire the GPS module to RX, TX pins RX to TX? how is it not working?

Comment: Yes, I wired the GPS and it is not working. I get some strange, longe output

Comment: does the baud rate match?

Comment: Yes, it matches

Answer (score 0):

NewSoftSerial is Arduino library for AVR ATmega MCU. It can't be used with other MCU Arduino platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thank you Juraj for help.
I used the Serial1 to obtain data from the GPS and it worked.
The code if someone also has that problem:

```
void setup() {
  Serial1.begin(9600);
  SerialUSB.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial1.available()) {
    char outp = Serial1.read();
    SerialUSB.print(outp);
  }
}
```